# AngularJS library angular-filter not working with radio button

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am using angular-filter "groupBy" (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) to display lessons within a subject as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in lessonList | filter:search | groupBy: 'lesson.subject.name'">
                    <div>
                        <strong> {{key}}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr ng-repeat="t in value">
                                <td>{{t.lesson.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{t.lesson.name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="t.status" ng-value="1"> Complete
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="t.status" ng-value="2"> Incomplete

                                    Selected Status: {{t.status}}
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I select the above status radio button for the first time, the value of status changes (from 1 to 2 and viceversa). I then save this information into a database. Now, if I leave this page and come back to this page again by clicking View and Edit button and click the radio buttons, the status inside "Selected Status: {{t.status}}" line changes, whereas the status inside the **lessonList** object does not change. I wrote another chunk of code to see the change in **lessonList** as follows and the **test.status** does not change with change in the radio button:

```
 <div>
      <ul ng-repeat="test in lessonList ">
         <li> {{test.lesson.id}}</li>
         <li> {{test.status}}</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

However, if I refresh the browser, and click the radio buttons in the Edit page, the **lessonList** updates. Is it because the {{value}} only updates and not the **lessonList**
How can I update the **lessonList** when the radio button changes? I need the lessonList object's status changed every time I change the radio button's value. My data looks like follows:

```
$scope.lessonList = [
 {lesson: {id: 1, name: 'Lesson 1', subject: {name: 'Maths', standard: 1},   status: 1},
 {lesson: {id: 2, name: 'Lesson 2', subject: {name: 'Maths', standard: 1}}, status: 2},
 {lesson: {id: 3, name: 'Lesson 1', subject: {name: 'Science', standard: 2}}, status: 1},
 {lesson: {id: 4, name: 'Lesson 3', subject: {name: 'Science', standard: 2}}, status: 2}
];
```

The **filter:search** is filtering on the standard i.e. search.subject.standard
Any help/suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How do you leave the page and come back without refreshing?

Comment: By refreshing, I meant browser refreshing (edited in the question). If I save the lesson information in the database for the first time and then come back to this page by clicking View  and Edit buttons. Then in the Edit section, if I click the radio buttons, it doesnot update the lessonList

Comment: I think it's probably a problem somewhere else - here's a plunker with everything above...can you modify it to reproduce the issue? http://plnkr.co/edit/wiOz1fQfkJyvh8ihQthi?p=preview

Comment: This is probably a copy/paste issue, but in lessonList, you're first lesson is missing a brace.

Comment: Thanks Brad, missing the brace was a copy-paste issue. The plunker you provided works perfectly fine, so does my code when its populated for the first time. After I save and exit of that page, I click View & Edit buttons to populate lessonList and bring back the radio buttons (exactly same code), but already populated with the DB data. Now when I change the radio buttons, it doesnot affect the lessonList, but updates the value variable. Thats the confusion :)

Comment: That sounds odd - can you include code that populates lessonList from the DB? It may also help to add the following to compare the data when it's working and not working - maybe there's a small structural difference somewhere.      <pre>{{lessonList | json}}</pre>